# Mutation SURVIVED but runtime exception was thrown in the code under test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mutation-testing, pitest

I have a Class calling a super-Method for registering a Bean Mapper. Other methods Use a super-Method for mapping Beans which relies on having the responsible Bean Mapper registered before.

If a Bean is being mapped without a matching registered Mapper, a custom Runtime-Exception is thrown.

When I remove the registration of the Bean-Mapper myself, 240 Tests are failing because the called super.map() method raises a Runtime-Exception.

But PIT tells me: SURVIVED.

`removed call to org/laladev/moneyjinn/businesslogic/service/impl/AbstractService::registerBeanMapper → SURVIVED`

Why?
Yes - At least one of the "Error"-Tests is listed as an examinded Test.

When I remove the line myself and execute all of my Tests, plenty of them are counted as Errors with:

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is Mapper undefined!`

It is a Spring Boot App and the container is fired up automatically during unittesting by Spring for all my "end user tests" (JSON/REST in+out) which are something like 95% of all my tests.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without seeing the code, but the most likely explanation are a) The failing tests are not unit tests and run the code in a different jvm than the test code b) The mutation is only exercised during class loading/initialisation. If you can provide a minimal project that reproduces the problem I can take a look.

Comment: Please checkout https://github.com/OlliL/moneyjinn-pitest. Just execute Test.java - it runs fine. Then open TestService, and comment line 33 (super.registerBeanMapper....) and run the test again - it fails with an Exception. PIT does the same but now states in this minimal example "NO_COVERAGE" - but this line is covered regarding to eclemma as it is called in the super Constructor of AbstractService

Comment: You've configured pit to look for tests in the 'moneyjinn' package, but your test is in a package called 'moneyjunn'. If you fix this the mutation on line 33 is killed.

Comment: Ok, this is just a typo in this test scenario. Seems to be harder to get a minimal setup for the issue I'm expecting. It is a Spring Boot app and the tests are executed with the Spring4JUnitRunner starting the complete application during the test (embedded tomcat and so on....)....

Comment: Is the tomcat actually embedded in the same process? If it's not that would explain the problem. If the code is executed in a different JVM than the tests then pitest will be unable to activate the mutation in the other JVM. Even if it could it would have no coverage data to work from for that JVM.

Comment: it is in the same JVM and it is mutated. pitest shows "SURVIVED" - so the mutation was done I guess